# How to reformat C code to put every struct or function definition in only one line?

Tags: c, reformatting

What I have:

```
int f() {
    Stmts....;
}
enum t {
    A,B,C
};
```

What I want:

```
int f() { Stmts...; }
enum t {A, B, C};
```

Also, I want the same effect for structs, unions, etc..
Thanks.

Comment: Find and replace line ending characters for your platform (`\n`, `\r\n`, or `\r`) with empty strings in your source file(s)?

Comment: Are you asking for a tool that does such a thing? (Yuck!) That would be out of scope for SO.

Comment: Do your function definitions extend beyond a single statement?

Comment: @Weather Vane yes, they can be multiple lines.

Comment: Here is one way to [obfuscate the code](http://www.sourceformat.com/obfuscate-code-cpp.htm). As you can see from the C example there, it renders code unreadable, although it doesn't remove every newline, which would make it even harder to read on this site, as posted code has no automatic line-wrap.

Comment: .. but having said that, the example code barely needed obfuscating in the first place.

Comment: If you are having trouble writing such a program, describe the troublesome part, and present what you attempted.